# Extract href values inside td tags in jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have

```
<table class="table" >
<tr>   
 <td><a href="url">text1</a></td>    
<td>text2</td> 

 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="url2">text</a></td> 
   <td>text</td> 

</tr>
```

and I want to extract the url and text of all rows
I use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
for (Element table : doc.select("table.table")) {
                for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                     Elements tds = row.select("td");
                           String text1=tds.get(0).text();
                           String url= row.attr("href");
                         System.out.println(text1+ "," + url);
                }
}
```

I get the text1 value but url is null.

How can I get the url from the td tags?

Answer (score 12):

Your row variable is not the `a` tag, so there is no attribute `href` on it.

Try with this:

```
Element table = doc.select("table.table");
Elements links = table.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link: links) {
    String url = link.attr("href");
    String text = link.text();
    System.out.println(text + ", " + url);
}
```

This is pretty much extracted from the [JSoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You (maybe some one else) can try with this:

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        for (Element table : doc.select("table.table")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                for (Element tds : row.select("td")) {
                    Elements links = tds.select("a[href]");
                    for (Element link : links) {
                        System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
                        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```